# How to create a pull request to merge only one commit from staging to production?

Tags: git, bitbucket

In my staging environment, I have many commits. For now, I have to merge only one commit to production not all of them. But when i created a pull request to merge this commit from staging to production, all the commits are attached to the pull request.

could anyone please tell me how can I merge just one commit with pull request?

Comment: You'd have to create a new branch with just that commit (you can cherry pick it) and PR from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout [production branch]
git checkout -b [new branch for cherry pick]
(you're now on the new branch)
git cherry-pick [commit hash you want]
```

You will now have the changes from that commit in your new branch. Push and Pull Request the new branch to your production branch.

`git cherry-pick -n` If you don't want to commit the pick right away.